# Request User Agent Outputs Mozilla/5.0 everytime

Tags: c#

Hi i am running a SuccessLogin() function and when importing the userAgent or browser name to detect whether im on the ipad, iphone, or desktop chrome, or whatever I use this code.

```
public void SucessLogin()
{
    String userAgent;
    userAgent = Request.UserAgent;

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand { CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.loginaudit ([login], [timestamp], [device], [loginerror]) VALUES (@login, @time, @device, 'Success')", Connection = sqlCon })
        {
            sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", DateTime.Now);
            sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@device", userAgent);
            sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", txtLoginID.Text);
            sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtPassword.Text);
            sqlCon.Open();
            {

                sqlCmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However it outputs this in the database when I'm on IE or Chrome.

Chrome:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
```

Internet Explorer:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Those are the correct user agents http://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/03/most-common-user-agents/. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: Is there any way to simplify it or no?

Comment: To simplify it to what?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [UA-Parser](https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser#usage--c) ?